# Row_number() over partition

Tags: row-number

I am working on peoplesoft. I have a requirement where I have to update the column value in a sequence ordered based on some ID.
For eg.

```
CA24100001648- 1
CA24100001648- 2
CA24100001664- 1
CA24100001664- 2
CA24100001664- 3
CA24100001664- 4
CA24100001664- 5
CA24100001664- 6
```

But, I am getting '1' as the value for all the rows on updating.

Here is my query, can anyone please help out on this.

```
UPDATE PS_UC_CA_CONT_STG C 
SET C.CONTRACT_LINE_NUM2 = ( SELECT row_number() over(PARTITION BY D.CONTRACT_NUM
                                                      order by  D.CONTRACT_NUM)
FROM PS_UC_CA_HDR_STG D 
WHERE C.CONTRACT_NUM=D.CONTRACT_NUM );
```

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaryV.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

update emp a
set comm = 
(with cnt as ( select deptno,empno,row_number() over (partition by deptno order by deptno) rn from emp)
select c.rn from cnt c where c.empno=a.empno)

Comment: I have tried with emp table and it's working, only thing it should have join on primary key.